# Make chartjs pie chart wiyh dynamic data

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I can't display my ChartJS pie chart with dynamic data, I googled a lot and I couldn't find a solution, so I'm here for your help.

```
 window.onload = function() {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
            dataType: "json",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function(data) {
              // var dataResults = data.d.results;
              var tempData = [{
                  EnterpriseProjectTypeName: 'first project'
                },
                {
                  EnterpriseProjectTypeName: 'first project'
                },
                               {
                  EnterpriseProjectTypeName: 'first project'
                },
                {
                  EnterpriseProjectTypeName: 'second project'
                },
                               {
                  EnterpriseProjectTypeName: 'third project'
                },
                {
                  EnterpriseProjectTypeName: 'test'
                }
              ];

              var itermeidiaryObject = {};
              $.each(tempData, function(key, value) {
                var epn = value.EnterpriseProjectTypeName;
                var som = 0;
                if (epn != null) {
                  itermeidiaryObject[epn] = ++itermeidiaryObject[epn] || 1;
                }
                var somme = som;
              });
              var finalObject = Object.keys(itermeidiaryObject).map(function(key) {
                return {
                  label: key,
                  y: itermeidiaryObject[key]
                }
              });

    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var lables=tempData
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
                labels: finalObject,
                datasets: [{

                    data: finalObject,

                }]
            },

        options: {
        responsive: false,
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              maxRotation: 90,
              minRotation: 80
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });

                  }
    });
       }
```

And this is the html part

```
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```

Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want a pie chart or a bar chart ?  Edited things a little so that it makes a pie chart, although you can just go back to the bar chart with a few edits regarding mostly the way labels were handled since it looks like they need to be single values in an array.  Probably a better way, but this should help.  This is for the pie chart.  You had a rogue div in the HTML also.

```js
window.onload = function() {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
            dataType: "json",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function(data) {
              // var dataResults = data.d.results;
              var tempData = [{
                  EnterpriseProjectTypeName: 'first project'
                },
                {
                  EnterpriseProjectTypeName: 'first project'
                },
                               {
                  EnterpriseProjectTypeName: 'first project'
                },
                {
                  EnterpriseProjectTypeName: 'second project'
                },
                               {
                  EnterpriseProjectTypeName: 'third project'
                },
                {
                  EnterpriseProjectTypeName: 'test'
                }
              ];

              var itermeidiaryObject = {};
              $.each(tempData, function(key, value) {
                var epn = value.EnterpriseProjectTypeName;
                var som = 0;
                if (epn != null) {
                  itermeidiaryObject[epn] = ++itermeidiaryObject[epn] || 1;
                }
                var somme = som;
              });
              var finalObject = Object.keys(itermeidiaryObject).map(function(key) {
                return {
                  label: key,
                  y: itermeidiaryObject[key]
                }
              });
              
              var pievalues = finalObject.map(function(value, index) {
                return value.y;
              });
              
              var labels = finalObject.map(function(value, index) {
                return value.label;
              });
              
              var colorscheme = colors.slice(0, labels.length);
              console.log(labels);
              console.log(pievalues);
              console.log(finalObject);

    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
             data: pievalues,
                  backgroundColor: colorscheme
          }]
            },

        options: {
        responsive: false,

      }
    });

     }
    });
}

var colors =  ["#0074D9", "#FF4136", "#2ECC40", "#FF851B", "#7FDBFF", "#B10DC9", "#FFDC00", "#001f3f", "#39CCCC", "#01FF70", "#85144b", "#F012BE", "#3D9970", "#111111", "#AAAAAA"];
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```

I am presuming that the data you provided in the handler success is pretty much what you get back as JSON ?

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me just the way I want. Thank you.